# Jacoco finds modules but doesn't run tests

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, pom.xml, jacoco

When I execute mvn clean install, the tests are found but not run:

```html
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running Test1
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
```

The jacoco.exec file is created but it dooesn't contain any information about the test.
I do have the following dependancies in my pom file:

- javax.servlet-api 4.0.1
- junit-jupiter-api 5.7.1
- junit-jupiter-engine 5.7.1
- javax.json-api 1.1.4
- jakarta.json 1.1.6

jacoco is integrated as a plugin:

```html
 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The other posts didn't help, unfortunately. I would be grateful for any help!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Would you add the Maven command that you use to run the build ?

Comment: Jacoco does not run tests.  Surefire runs tests. Examining the jacoco configuration will not be useful here. You need to look at your tests and how they are defined, along with the surefire configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven)

Add the following lines to your maven.

```html
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And make sure that your test-classes begin or end with "Test" and that the functions start with "test..."!